# MySQL: World Database Special Chars are Missing?

Tags: mysql, database, special-characters

I'm using the MySQL World Database, but it seems that the special chars like `á`, `é` are missing, they are changed with a `?` sign:

[image]

Is this my fault? Or is the database designed in this way, just because I looked in the `world.sql` file and I found that some chars are missing, or my textmate is wrong:

[image]

As you can see in this picture instead of `Győr` it is `Gyˆr` and others too.

**Some Info:**

I'm on a MAC OS X 10.6, and I have followed these instructions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/world-setup.html . and I downloaded the [MyISAM version of the world database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html).

Comment: Pretty sure it's your fault. I just downloaded the thing and everything looks fine. Make sure all your environments know about the right encodings everywhere etc.

Comment: @Kerrek SB what do you mean by `Make sure all your environments know about the right encodings everywhere`?

Comment: Well, make sure that you're displaying the data in the encoding that your enviroment expects... the file uses Latin-1 encoding (ISO-8859-1), perhaps you need to convert it to whatever you are using (maybe UTF-8?).

Comment: @Kerrek SB I run this: `ALTER DATABASE world CHARACTER SET utf8;` but nothing has changed, I also tried altering each tables with `ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;` and still nothing

Comment: No no no, not the data base schema. Your actual source file, `world.sql`, is in Latin-1. You have to make sure that you respect that. Have you tried inserting the table from the command line, `mysql ... < world.sql`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, do you mean: `mysql> SOURCE world.sql;` ?

Comment: @KerrekSB let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1083/discussion-between-cirk-and-kerrek-sb)

Comment: @CIRK: I am having the same problem. You never accepted an answer here. May be you can answer it yourself and accept it if none of the answers below were correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `world.sql` file already specifies the tables with "latin1" default charset. Thus there is no need to explicitly define any charset for the database or tables.

Two things:

1. what editor are you using to view "world.sql"? I tried to view in Notepad++ on Windows7 and it showed all the characters? So perhaps your editor isn't supporting the latin charset.
2. How did you import "world.sql" into MySQL?

   i. If you copied the contents from the file and pasted directly into MySQL, either using the default client or any available GUI clients, then it is likely that the special characters did not import correctly because the editor from where you had copied already lost them. Please try importing directly into MySQL from the command line using something like `mysql -uXXX -hXXX -p < world.sql`

   ii. If you did import it from the command line, then I believe your content imported fine with the special characters. Perhaps your client, the black screen shot I suppose, isn't supporting the special characters.

So, please investigate which of the above 2 cases might be happening. Though I'm not sure if there might well be a third case if both of the above fail. But I hope it helps.

Comment: I imported it from the command line with `SOURCE path/to/world.sql`, I have TextMate and I figured out with the help of @Kerrek SB that it shows good if I change its encoding to `Latin1` in both textmate, and the terminal in mac. But I wan't to use the data in the browser where I need to use UTF-8 Encoding, so I need to transform somehow the Latin1 to UTF-8.

Comment: Great @CIRK! Though you don't need to convert to UTF-8 just for the purpose of showing it on the browser. Please read on MySQL's connection character sets (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check your `my.cnf` file? 
I had to put these lines to let MySQL work properly with cyrillic characters:

```
# [mysqld] section

skip-character-set-client-handshake
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, the problem is that I have several `my.conf` files under `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_test/etc..` , but I have one called `mysqlaccess.conf` at `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` , so which one should I change?

Comment: I think you should try `/usr/local/mysql/bin/`. If you find there line `[mysqld]`, you should put these 3 lines from my answer there and restart MySQL daemon. I don't have any expirience with Macs. For example, on CentOS (Linux) it's stored in `/etc/my.cnf`.

Answer (score 0):

On gedit/Ubuntu, when I opened it with **Western (ISO-8859-15)** it displays special characters correctly.

Earlier, I had the same problem and I had let gedit detect encoding automatically, which replaced the special characters with `?`. I also tried with UTF-8 which gave me an error.

So, if your editor has this setting, the encoding I have specified should work for you as well.